# d3.scaleBand is not a function

Tags: meteor, d3.js

I am using d3 with meteor

Here is how my client/main.html looks like.

I get the d3.scaleBand() not a function.

I tried importing different versions of d3 but the same result.

Comment: at least check once after uploading a question

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to install the [d3-scale package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-scale) to get access to the d3.scaleBand() function?